# How can I center 3 tables?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created 3 separate tables and used `<table style="float: left;">` so they would be next to each other and they will still look good on mobile. But the problem is the whole thing is aligned to the left because of the float I did. Can anyone help me to move them to the center?

Jules

This is the HTML and CSS that I used:

```
/*** HTML Table Code **/
<div class="table-title"></div>
<table style="float: left;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-left">Why...</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
<td class="text-left">You’ll know exactly what are your priorities all the time.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="float: left;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-left">Who...</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
<td class="text-left">are you talking to and how to deliver in the best possible way your message.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="float: left;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="text-left">How...</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-hover">
<tr>
<td class="text-left">to start and automating your business without spending time that you don’t have.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


/*** CSS Table Styles **/
table {
    table-layout: fixed!important;
  background: white;
  border-radius:32px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: auto!important;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 280px;
  padding:20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

th {
    padding-top:20px!important;
    padding-bottom:20px!important;
    text-transform:capitalize;
  color:#ffffff;
  background:#ff5722;
  border-bottom:4px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  font-size:22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:40px;
  text-align:left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align:middle;
}

td {
    height:80px!important;
    padding-top:30px!important;
    vertical-align: text-top!important;
    padding-bottom:30px!important;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:40px;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight:300;
    line-height:24px;
  font-size:16px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
```

Comment: Wrap all three tables inside div with margin left and right auto.

Comment: Hi @Manjunath, can you give me an example code please?

Comment: I don't think it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I don't know if you know bootstrap 4 framework? You can easily organised your screen in colums.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Have a look at this sample code from the documentation :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a row that contains 3 columns and you can easily add your tables in those columns (this is also responsive!)

Let me know if you have more questions I am happy to help.

Comment: Oh man, I don't know bootstrap yet. Let me try if I can do that.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions

Answer (score -1):

I did a similar thing when building my website I had two tables which I needed to display next to each other. My solution was to float one table to the right and the other to the left it worked as I needed it to.

As for your problem try doing this:

float first table to the right the second table center and the third to the left, might work.

or,

when I have three tables I normally do this:

display the first table on top as the size of two tables (table 2 and 3),
display the other two tables on bottom table 2 float left and table 3 float right.
Refer this picture to get an idea:

[image: how to align 3 things(images,tables) in a website easily]

or you can use use bootstrap rows and columns as mentioned by fearcoder.

Comment: Hi! I have thought of those ideas but I don't think it will work for my goal. But thanks though.

Comment: Ok, no problem.